# What should be format for input data while Testing the endpoints of deployed Prophet Time-series model in Azure-ML?

Tags: python, azure, time-series, azure-web-app-service, facebook-prophet

I have trained and deployed a fbProphet time-series model using mlflow and Azure. The model was properly registered and logged with all the required entities. I was able to deploy the model in Azure-ML and generate the endpoints.
My training dataframe looks like :

```
    df =  pd.DataFrame(
{'ds': ['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 02:00:00', '2023-01-01 03:00:00'],
            'y': [20, 21, 19, 18]})
```

Now I want to test those endpoints. Under the testing-section, I see

```
{
  "input_data" : 
}
```

I am unable to figure out exactly what data(please provide example) and in which format should be entered here to test my time-series prophet model.

P.S. - I have tried many combinations and everytime i am getting error.
for e.g.

**1-**  using json on the data

```
json.dumps({'data': df.to_dict(orient='records')})
```

and feeding the its output here:

```
{
      "input_data":[{"ds": "2021-01-01 00:00:00", "y": 23.55}, {"ds": "2021-01-01 01:00:00", "y": 26.28}]
    }
```

***Error*** - *Failed to test real-time endpoint
{"message":"only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"}*

**2-** trying other combinations

```
{
  "input_data" :{"ds":{"1":"2023-04-01 22:00:00", "2": "2023-04-01 23:00:00"}
}
```

***Error:*** Failed to test real-time endpoint
{"message":"POST body could not be decoded as JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 2 (char 81)"}

**3-** feeding only dates

```
{
  "input_data" :["2023-04-01 22:00:00","2023-04-01 23:00:00"]
}
```

**then**

```
{
  "input_data" :[[1,2], ["2023-04-01 22:00:00","2023-04-01 23:00:00"]]
}
```

***Error :*** Failed to test real-time endpoint
{"message":"only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"}

**And likewise, i tried many more ways. But not able to figure out my mistake. Please help me, what i am missing-out ?**

Comment: Did you get it working? I too stuck with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this format below and worked for me (don't remove index otherwise it will not work)

```
{
"input_data": {
    "columns": [
        "age", "sex", "trestbps", "chol", "fbs", "restecg", "thalach", "exang", "oldpeak", "slope", "ca", "thal"
    ],
    "index": [1],
    "data": [
        [1, 1, 145, 233, 1, 2, 150, 0, 2.3, 3, 0, 2]
    ]
}}
```

I have got the answer from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-mlflow-models?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azureml#payload-example-for-a-json-serialized-pandas-dataframes-in-the-split-orientation)